# Get the entire row of Firebase Database on Autocompletetextview Item click

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, android-adapter

i want to display some specific values in the same row as the item that is clicked in the autocompletetextview.

```
final AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autocompleteView);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(autoComplete);
    autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
        {
            String item = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: What problem you are getting?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i cannot get the other values in the same row as the String item